# Chain rule involving Fréchet derivative

Tags: integration, frechet-derivative, variational-analysis

Suppose that $P(w)$ is a probability density function with support $w \in [0,\infty)$ and $G = G[P]$ is a functional satisfying $G[P] \in [0,1]$. I saw a paper used a chain rule of the following form:
$$\frac{dG}{dt} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\delta G}{\delta P(w)}\,\frac{\partial P(w)}{\partial t}\,dw, $$ in which $\frac{\delta G}{\delta P(w)}$ represents the Fréchet/variational derivative of $G$ and $P(w) = P(w,t)$ is now a time-dependent probability density. May I know why such a chain rule holds? My main concern is the appearance of the integral $\int_0^\infty \,dw$.

Remark: for any sufficiently well behaved function $\eta(w)$, the relation $$\left\langle \frac{\delta G}{\delta P(w)}, \eta \right\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{G[P+\epsilon\,\eta] - G[P]}{\epsilon} $$ defines the Fréchet derivative.

Comment: What norms/metrics do you take to differentiate?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven the usual $L^2$ norm induced by the inner product

Comment: I am a bit confused. The probability densities need not be in $L^1$, so that will not be a norm on the probability densities, right?

Comment: Of course I meant "need not to be $L^2$".

Comment: @SeverinSchraven if you have an answer to this question in mind, you can post it, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not have an answer yet. Still a bit confused about the norms involved.

Comment: In fact the formula makes no sense to me. The problem is that the Fréchet derivative of $G$ is again a functional on some subset of $L^1$. However, this means that there is no dependence on $w$ after applying the Fréchet derivative of $G$ to the time derivative of the probability density. Maybe you can give us the reference of the paper.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven the link is https://click.endnote.com/viewer?doi=10.1007%2Fs10955-015-1316-8&token=WzIyODE2MzksIjEwLjEwMDcvczEwOTU1LTAxNS0xMzE2LTgiXQ.6eoD7HqjIBYjoL7GrWeDOEOX22w

Comment: The paper is titled "An $H$ Theorem for Boltzmann's Equation for the Yard-Sale Model of Asset Exchange : The Gini Coefficient as an $H$ functional", 2015. My question concerns about the validity of formula (9) there, which is written in the OP.

Comment: I had a look at the paper. This result follows from the explicite form of our functional. This is nothing general. I do not see why this should follow from the chain rule.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven But I do believe this formula is valid in the general situation in these author's mind, you do not need to know the explicit form of $G$ or $\frac{\delta G}{\delta P(w)}$ for this to be valid I guess. I mean, (7) is given so that you can arrive at (8), but I think they mention (9) because this is a general result.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is a general result. Already their use of the $L^2$ inner product to represent the derivative is more than questionable (as I pointed out above, this is not the correct norm for this space). Maybe there are some secret assumptions that make that true, but in general... I don't think so.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I see, I will add a bounty to this question in a few days to see if someone else will be willing to help on the resolution of this question

Comment: Indeed, I am curious to see the answer. I suspect that there might be some assumption that is common in this field that makes it work. Anyways, sorry that I was not much of a help.

Comment: No worries!  Thank you very much!

Comment: why the delete? it was right except possibly for the term 'event' https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4107312

Comment: I do not want to argue on that part. Maybe our background and understanding of the concepts are just different. Thanks